# sqlsrv driver for Windows PHP PDO SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server, windows-7

I've added and enabled in php.ini given .dll, got Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client, previously configured it successfully on 2 other machines, but on my local one It just says `could not find driver` have I missed something?

php.ini: `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll`

script: `new PDO("sqlsrv:Server={$_dbConfig['server']};Database={$_dbConfig['dbName']}", $_dbConfig['username'], $_dbConfig['password'])`

In php error log I get strange: `[08-Nov-2014 18:18:31 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:  in Unknown on line 0` but have no idea why, php.ini itself is configured as my other working machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change in `php.ini`:
`extension_dir = "ext"` to `extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext"`

Got it from here: https://serverfault.com/a/240012/193005